# Display true/false custom field as checkbox in Liferay

Tags: checkbox, liferay, custom-fields

When you create a boolean custom field of type true/false it is displayed as a drop-down box with true and false as values. When I go and edit the field and don't see an option that allows to change the display type. I would like to have this field rendered as a checkbox. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't fidn any configuration option for this type of field as it is with some others. The way that I found to render the true/false as a checkbox is to override the jsp from the taglib that renders custom attributes. [Here](http://liferay.bdedov.eu/2012/02/render-truefalse-custom-field-type-as.html) I have described what is needed to be done.

http://liferay.bdedov.eu/2012/02/render-truefalse-custom-field-type-as.html

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to create a `jsp` hook for `page.jsp` at `html\taglib\ui\custom_attribute\` and replace the `select` with a `checkbox`:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="<%= type == ExpandoColumnConstants.BOOLEAN %>">
        <% Boolean curValue=( Boolean)value; if (curValue==n ull) { curValue=( Boolean)defaultValue; } curValue=P aramUtil.getBoolean(request, "ExpandoAttribute--" + escapedName + "--", curValue); %>
            <select id="<%= randomNamespace %><%= escapedName %>" name="<portlet:namespace />ExpandoAttribute--<%= escapedName %>--">
                <option <%=c urValue ? "selected" : "" %>value="1">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="true" />
                </option>
                <option <%=! curValue ? "selected" : "" %>value="0">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="false" />
                </option>
            </select>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```